# Why I cannot read the temperature / humidity sensor SHT20?

Tags: raspbian, kernel, i2c, driver

I use a temperature and humidity sensor sht20. According to this link: http://www.sensirion.com/en/products/humidity-temperature/humidity-temperature-sensor-sht2x/ It is compatible with sht21, which has a linux kernel module driver in drivers/hwmon/sht21.c

For my raspberry Pi B+, I recompiled the kernel of 3.18.1+ to enable HWMON and SHT21 module. I successfully update the kernel image and modules to my Pi. And I refer to this link: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=7086

Do below (as root):

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

And then,

```
echo sht21 0x40 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
```

Do again,

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I installed latest version lm_sensors by make && make install from the source code. Then I typed

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sensors
bcm2835_thermal-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +36.9掳C  

sht21-i2c-1-40
Adapter: bcm2708_i2c.1
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp1_input: I/O error
temp1:            N/A  

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sensors-detect 
...
Sorry, no sensors were detected.
...
```

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use a kernel *without* that driver and run `i2cdetect`?  It should still show up, and checking that might demonstrate that it is the driver that is the problem.

Comment: You do know that `UU` indicates *"Probing was skipped, because this address is currently in use by a driver."* (`man i2cdetect`)?  But just because someone wrote a driver for it doesn't mean it works (and it appears that it does not). Do you have a datasheet and documentation for the device?  If you are decent with C, you could try going through that and using the smbus API to create a userspace driver.  Probably not that much code...I have a C++ example of this for a temp/pressure sensor [here](http://cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/BMP085/BMP085_C++.tar.bz2).

Comment: Thank you for your info! (1) I find an example code in user space which can get sensor data from SHT20, http://www.emsystech.de/raspi-sht21/ And it may use GPIO to act as i2c. (2) I am writing code using open/ioctl/write/read to operate /dev/i2c-1, this way may be hardware independent and easily porting to other Linux device. (3) I just want to use this chance to learn more about Linux kernel. That is why I asked over and over on difference between user space and kernel space, and try to make this kernel way work. @goldilocks