# How can Rpi4B use python to talk to the I2C DHT20 / SHT20 temperature and humidity sensor?

Tags: pi-4, i2c, sensor, temperature

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi 4 to read an I2C temperature and humidity sensor. The part I'm using is a module from Grove based on the DHT20 sensor. Here's a link to a page about the module:

https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Temperature-Humidity-Sensor-V2-0-DHT20-p-4967.html

I need some help programming the I2C communication. The specs sheet for the sensor explains the frames that are needed for correct communication (see page 8):

https://files.seeedstudio.com/products/101020932/DHT20-Product-Manual.pdf

I would be grateful if someone could show me the Python code needed to get a sensor reading. Preferably this would be based on the smbus package, but I will be grateful for any solution (based on whatever package you prefer). I understand that there are many answers about the DHT11 and DHT22 sensors, but these older models have one-wire logic whereas the newer DHT20 has I2C.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reliable temperature/humidity logging with Python and a DHT11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/reliable-temperature-humidity-logging-with-python-and-a-dht11)

Comment: @Milliways: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately the DHT11 and DHT22 are older models that use one-wire logic. The DHT20 is a newer model with I2C logic, so none of the DHT11 and DHT22 solutions will work. I have edited my post to clarify this difference. But I appreciate you trying to help!

Comment: a search for *dht20 python* yielded (amongst many) [this result](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_DHT20) - there is a raspberry pi folder there! 

Comment: (1) AHT20 - Temperature & Humidity Sensor Breakout Board Product Sheet - Adafruit US$4.50
https://www.adafruit.com/product/4566

(2) AHT20 - Temperature & Humidity Sensor Breakout Board Learning Guide- Adafruit
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-aht20

(3) AHT20 Temperature Sensor Datasheet - aosong
http://www.aosong.com/en/products-32.html

(4) Why are DHT11/DHT22 problematic? - AdaFruit
https://learn.adafruit.com/modern-replacements-for-dht11-dht22-sensors/why-are-they-probelmatic

/ to continue, ...

Comment: (5) What are better alternatives to DHT11/DHT22? - AdaFruit
https://learn.adafruit.com/modern-replacements-for-dht11-dht22-sensors/what-are-better-alternatives

(6) DHT20 GitHub Home - DFRobot
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_DHT20

(7) DHT20 GitHub Python - DFRobot
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_DHT20/tree/master/python/raspberrypi

Comment: (8) ***DHT20 GitHub Python Readme*** - DFRobot
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_DHT20/blob/master/python/raspberrypi/README.md

(9) ***DHT20 GitHub Python Program*** - DFRobot 
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_DHT20/blob/master/python/raspberrypi/DFRobot_DHT20.py

(10) ***DHT20 GitHub Python Example*** - DFRobot
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_DHT20/blob/master/python/raspberrypi/examples/get_data.py

Comment: (11) SHT20 Humidity Sensor Product Sheet - Sensirion
https://www.sensirion.com/en/environmental-sensors/humidity-sensors/humidity-temperature-sensor-sht2x-digital-i2c-accurate/

(12) SHT20 Digital Humidity Sensor Datasheet - Sensirion
https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/2_Humidity_Sensors/Datasheets/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT20_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: (13) SHT20 I2C 3V3/5V humidity sensor module - US$1.75
https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005001658779750.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.3b2c4713npuJhb&algo_pvid=7757d995-f018-4e74-bdaf-b4e66b1a2d7e&algo_exp_id=7757d995-f018-4e74-bdaf-b4e66b1a2d7e-8

Comment: (14) Why I cannot read the I2C temperature / humidity sensor SHT20?, RpiSE, Asked 6 years, 10 months ago, Active 6 years, 10 months ago, Viewed 3k times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26978/why-i-cannot-read-the-temperature-humidity-sensor-sht20

Comment: (15) [SHT20 Temperature and Humidity Sensor] I2C slave device address bouncing around [closed] - EESE, Asked 6 months ago Active 6 months ago Viewed 106 times
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563825/i2c-slave-device-address-bouncing-around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First start by finding the I2C address of your sensor. Here's an explanation of how to do that: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c (look under the section "Testing I2C").

Once you have the address, try the following Python code:

```
import time
import smbus

address = 0x38 #Put your device's address here

i2cbus = smbus.SMBus(1)
time.sleep(0.5)

data = i2cbus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0x71,1)
if (data[0] | 0x08) == 0:
  print('Initialization error')

i2cbus.write_i2c_block_data(address,0xac,[0x33,0x00])
time.sleep(0.1)

data = i2cbus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0x71,7)

Traw = ((data[3] & 0xf) << 16) + (data[4] << 8) + data[5]
temperature = 200*float(Traw)/2**20 - 50

Hraw = ((data[3] & 0xf0) >> 4) + (data[1] << 12) + (data[2] << 4)
humidity = 100*float(Hraw)/2**20

print(temperature)
print(humidity)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly, and I appreciate how simple you kept the code. That really helps for people who are still learning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like smbus is deprecated, but [`smbus2`](https://smbus2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) works as well. Just adapt the code of @ultracold:

```py
import time
import smbus2
    
address = 0x38 #Put your device's address here
    
i2cbus = smbus2.SMBus(1)
time.sleep(0.5)
    
data = i2cbus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0x71,1)
if (data[0] | 0x08) == 0:
   print('Initialization error')
    
i2cbus.write_i2c_block_data(address,0xac,[0x33,0x00])
time.sleep(0.1)
    
data = i2cbus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0x71,7)
    
Traw = ((data[3] & 0xf) << 16) + (data[4] << 8) + data[5]
temperature = 200*float(Traw)/2**20 - 50
    
Hraw = ((data[3] & 0xf0) >> 4) + (data[1] << 12) + (data[2] << 4)
humidity = 100*float(Hraw)/2**20
    
print(temperature)
print(humidity)
```